# how to insert data from one table to another table with some changes in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to know about the insert data from table to another table.

I have tried this query,

```
insert into new table_name
select * from old table
```

this query execute successfully for one table to another table but i want some changes in new table.

Example : Suppose I have 2 tables and each table column name :

```
 FirstName(varchar(max)) 
 MiddleName(varchar(max)) 
 last name(varchar(max))
```

I inserted 5000 records in each table.

I want to insert these table data into new table and new table column `Name` :

```
FirstName(varchar(max)) MiddleName(varchar(max)) last name(varchar(max)) 
S_No(int)(primarykey)
```

How to automatically generate and add number in `S_No` column when data is inserting?

Comment: Couldnt you just set S_No with auto increment?

Comment: **Don't overuse `VARCHAR(MAX)`** - use it when you **really** need it - and I really don't think you'll ever have a name that's 2 billion characters long .... [and **YES**, it does matter for performance!](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/whats-the-point-of-using-varchar%28n%29-anymore/)

Answer (score 0):

Use the same query but with column names in both select and Insert statements. Make S_No column as autoidentity(1,1). Then it should work.

`insert into new_table_name(firstname,middlename,lastname)
select firstname,middlename,lastname from othertable`

Comment: Autoidentity is not actually a datatype. You can set it through designer or through script.

`Alter table tableName add S_No int autoidentity(1,1)`

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'autoidentity'. when execute this query "Alter table New_Import_Test add S_No int autoidentity(1,1);"

Comment: oops.. `Alter table tableName add S_No int identity(1,1)`

Comment: Msg 2705, Level 16, State 4, Line 1
Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'S_No' in table 'New_Import_Test' is specified more than once.

Comment: That means you have already added this column to the table..
drop the column and recreate using the above script.
Drop column syntax. `ALTER TABLE YourTableName
DROP COLUMN S_No`